# Why does the system call "read()" block my program?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I am contacting you because I have a problem with my program. For my studies, I am currently programming in C a function to read a file, I am only allowed to use the following functions/system calls: **malloc, free, exit, (f)open, (f)close, (f)read, (f)write, getline, ioctl, usleep, sigaction, signal, stat, lstat, fstat**

The problem is that when calling my function my_filetostr(), it blocks the program at the read() system call and nothing happens.

here's my code:

```
char *my_filetostr(const char *filepath)
{
    int fd = 0;
    struct stat s;
    char *buff = NULL;
    if (fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY) > 0) {
        stat(filepath, &s);
        buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * s.st_size + 1);
        my_printf("fd : %d, size : %d\n", fd, s.st_size);
        if (read(fd, buff, s.st_size) == s.st_size) {
            buff[s.st_size] = '\0';
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

I specify that my file exists (my error handling works).

I tried to put some my_printf (we had to recode printf) in order to see where the program stops and to display some useful information:

- So I know that the problem comes from read()
- st_size returns the right size and filedescriptor has a correct value.

The program is just supposed to move on.

Comment: Your code has a minor TOCTOU bug.  You should use fstat when you have an open file handle.

Comment: `fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY) > 0` assigns `open(filepath, O_RDONLY) > 0` to `fd`.

Comment: By the way, 0 is a valid file descriptor. The comparison should have been `!= -1` anyway.

Comment: @stark `fstat()` is still a TOCTOU bug - the size of the file can change, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to fd inside the `if` condition.

This usually causes bugs and [should be avoided](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/assignment-in-if-condition.html)

Your issue here is specifically because `>` has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) compared to `=`, so `fd` becomes 1 which is [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)).

I have modified your code to highlight the issue
https://godbolt.org/z/M4PbcPfev

> fd : 1, size : 140728905723182

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @stark , @user3840170 , @tejas

My code now works :

```
char *my_filetostr(const char *filepath)
{
    int fd = -1;
    struct stat s;
    char *buff = NULL;
    if ((fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY)) != -1) {
        fstat(fd, &s);
        buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * s.st_size + 1);
        if (read(fd, buff, s.st_size) == s.st_size) {
            buff[s.st_size] = '\0';
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

I have performed the following actions:

- Replace stat with fstat (but that didn't solve the problem)
- Replace `int fd = 0` by `int fd = -1`
- Replace `fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY) > 0` par `(fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY)) != -1`

Thank you for your answers.